# Calculating the strength tensor of a vector field

Tags: tensors, differential-geometry

I'm trying to calculate

$$T_{ab} = g_{ab}F_{gd}F^{gd} - F_a^g F_{bg},$$
where
$$F_{ab} = \partial_a A_b-\partial_b A_a$$

So I define $F_{ab}$ by:

```
s[a_, b_] := D[v[b], a] - D[v[a], b]
```

and $g_{ab}$ is given as:

```
metric = DiagonalMatrix[{-1, 1, 1, 1}];    
m[a_, b_] := metric[[a, b]];
```

How can I now calculate $F^{ab}$ and $F_a^b$?

Comment: Use $F^{ab}=g^{al}g^{bm}F_{lm}$, where $g^{ik}$ is inverse to $g_{ik}$ so that $g_{ik}g^{kl}=\delta ^l_i$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev. What about the mixed tensor $F^g_b$? If it will be defined by the mixed metric $g^g_b$, how $g^g_b$ will be defined?

Comment: Use $F^a_b=g^{al}F_{lb}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexTrounev

Comment: You are welcome! :)